# Asynchronous loading of images on a HTML page

Tags: html, image

I have 4 image html elements on my page.

I have read somewhere (cannot remember/find where) that images are loaded independently of the rest of the html page.

So, if load 4 images via timers at the same time like so:

```
 tmrImage1 = setTimeout('Load Image 1 Function), 10000);
 tmrImage2 = setTimeout('Load Image 2 Function), 10000);
 tmrImage3 = setTimeout('Load Image 3 Function), 10000);
 tmrImage4 = setTimeout('Load Image 4 Function), 10000);
```

Will the images load sequentially or independently of each other?

Not sure if I know what I am talking about though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new Image()` will always load it's image .src asynchronously and independently of other images being loaded. Since they are independently loaded, they are not guaranteed to be loaded sequentially.

Here is an example of an image loader that preloads all desired images and then calls start.  When start is called, all the images have been fully loaded and are ready to be displayed:

```
// image loader

// put the paths to your images in imageURLs[]
var imageURLs=[];  
// push all your image urls!
imageURLs.push("images/image1.png");
imageURLs.push("images/image2.png");
imageURLs.push("images/image3.png");
imageURLs.push("images/image4.png");

// the loaded images will be placed in imgs[]
var imgs=[];

var imagesOK=0;
loadAllImages(start);

function loadAllImages(callback){
    for (var i=0; i<imageURLs.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        imgs.push(img);
        img.onload = function(){ 
            imagesOK++; 
            if (imagesOK>=imageURLs.length ) {
                callback();
            }
        };
        img.onerror=function(){alert("image load failed");} 
        img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
        img.src = imageURLs[i];
    }      
}

function start(){

    // the imgs[] array now holds fully loaded images
    // the imgs[] are in the same order as imageURLs[]

}
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your code and so quickly! Just 1 further question/scenario...  I am looking to update these 4 images continuously (like a poor man animation). It has to be done via updating jpgs (10Kb size each)  . I was looking to see what if it would be quicker/best waiting for each image to load or set all 4 of in a timer.  I guess I need to experiment with ur code and the info from Bob above,  thanks. Will get back with results...

Comment: The order of image loading will not likely be in original order. More likely that smaller sized images will load more quickly.  My code above does guarantee both sequential order and fully loaded images, but alternatively, you could put all 4 of your images on a spritesheet and so you would be downloading 1 image with 4 sub-images.  Then you can use the clipping version of context.drawImage to sequentially "animate" through the sprites.  Good luck with your project!

Comment: thanks for your info. Much appreciated.  I originally looked at using sprites a long time ago.  I spent a lot of time on it. But, the memory allocation goes up very high/exponentially every time the image clipping region changed which is a shame.  Apparently, it is the issue with using sprites.

Comment: When you say "image clipping region", are you referring to `context.clip`?  I'm thinking instead of `context.drawImage( srcImage, clipLeft, clipTop, clipWidth, clipHeight, drawLeft, drawTop, drawWidth, drawHeight)` which hasn't driven up my memory usage.

Comment: Ah, you mean using the canvas control. I see, I have found using the canavs control on mobile devices can slow my animations down depending of course on the mobile model being used due to the accelerate graphics being not ideal for some.  But, that could be a wrong conclusions though..

Comment: Yes, the canvas element is slower on mobile for sure.  Perhaps the image loader in my code above will be better in your mobile environment.

Comment: Hi, I am certainly going to give it a go. I am just waiting for a stress test to finish 1st though.  I am concerned about using the 'push' method though as I have found in the past it accrues memory over a period of time..

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of `setTimeout` the browser will open multiple connections to download images, etc.  There are tests on the web that will let you test your particular browser.  Search "browser maximum connections."

Given that information, and assuming you have at least four remaining connections from your browser's limit, the four images will start downloading one after another as the `setTimeout` functions fire because JavaScript is single-threaded.  They'll all start within a very short time.  The smallest image will (probably) finish first, etc.

Edited to add: JavaScript can *trigger* browser events, but in the case of downloading images, and probably many other events, it is the browser, not JavaScript, that *completes* the action.  That means the fact that JavaScript is single-threaded is of concern only in that such events are triggered in a given order.

Comment: Hi, Bob. Interesting info - and thanks.  I was looking to try and simulate multi-threading in JavaScript :).  If i opened 4 browser windows and each page loaded just 1 image would it be fair to say that 4 threads are created?

Comment: You have gotten into the internals of browsers, which is beyond my pay grade.  However, my guess is that what you would have is four instances of JavaScript running in four browser instances, and so four OS-level processes, not four threads.

Comment: Beyond my pay grade too :) Yes, process instead of threading. I am wondering if I can achieve this using iFrames?  I need to experiment. Thanks

Comment: Interesting addition/edit.  Now that you said it now sounds so obvious. I am going to do some tests with a few things and report back shortly. thanks again